# How to change color of text when added column in google chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yejD.png)

I trying change text color to white which pointed with an arrow in the picture, tried annotations.style, but it didn't work. What I do wrong?

```
    let dataTemperatures = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([]);
    dataTemperatures.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
    dataTemperatures.addColumn('number', 'External Temperature');
    dataTemperatures.addColumn('number', 'Dew Point');

    dataTemperatures.addRows(temperature_data);

    let temperature_options = {
        backgroundColor: chartBackgroundColor,
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: textChartColor,
            fontName: fontNameChart
        },
        annotations: {
           textStyle: {color: 'white'}
        },
        hAxis: {
            textStyle: { color: textChartColor },
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: "Temperatures (°C)",
            titleTextStyle: {
                color: textChartColor,
                fontName: fontNameChart
            },
            textStyle: { color: textChartColor },
        },
        series: {
            0: { type: 'line', color: '#1CACDC' },
            1: { type: 'line', color: '#00ffff'  }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following option to change the text color for the **legend**

```
legend: {
  textStyle: {
    color: textChartColor 
  }
}
```